# How to add subscripts to ggplot2 axis.text

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

I want to use subscripts within each factor in a ggplot barplot.

```
d = structure(list(env = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("mean SS", 
"50% O2 @ 25 °C", "50% O2 @ 0 °C", "50% O2 @ 10 °C", "anoxic @ 0 °C", 
"anoxic @ 25 °C", "anoxic @ 10 °C"), class = "factor"), pco2_inc = c(60, 
138.652445968464, 144.328210839879, 112.560395996095, 173.615572249453, 
234.86228704132, 209.102964222973)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Given the data.frame above, I want to produce a plot like this:

```
ggplot(d, aes(env, pco2_inc)) + geom_col()
```

[image: plot]

How can I make the `2` in `O2` subscripted for all the bar labels?

I've seen how the entire x axis label can be changed:

```
labs(x = expression(paste('50% ', O[2], ' @ 0 °C')))
```

but can't find how to get the `axis.text` to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to turn the `env` strings into valid `plotmath` expressions, so that they can be parsed properly. The code below takes care of that, though I'd be surprised if there isn't a more elegant approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

d = d %>%
  arrange(pco2_inc) %>% 
  mutate(env=gsub("O2", "O[2]", env),
         env=gsub(" ", "~", env),
         env=gsub("@", "'@'", env),
         env=gsub("%", "*'%'", env),
         env=gsub("~°", "*degree*", env))
```

> ```
>                           env pco2_inc
> 1                     mean~SS  60.0000
> 2 50*'%'~O[2]~'@'~25*degree*C 112.5604
> 3  50*'%'~O[2]~'@'~0*degree*C 138.6524
> 4 50*'%'~O[2]~'@'~10*degree*C 144.3282
> 5       anoxic~'@'~0*degree*C 173.6156
> 6      anoxic~'@'~25*degree*C 209.1030
> 7      anoxic~'@'~10*degree*C 234.8623
> ```

```
ggplot(d, aes(reorder(env, pco2_inc), pco2_inc)) + geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=parse(text=unique(d$env))) +
  theme_classic(base_size=12) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(colour="black", face="bold")) +
  labs(x="env")
```

[image]

Comment: When I run this code with a fresh session I am getting an error: `Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found `

Comment: That happened to me a few times when I was working on this answer. It [seems to be font-related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581440/error-in-grid-calll-textbounds-as-graphicsannotxlabel-xx-xy-polygon). I found that if I ran the code a few times, the plot eventually rendered. I haven't tried to resolve the underlying font issue yet.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how I can also incorporate a line break into this too? I'm trying to figure it out but can't find the magic combo of quotes, slashes, and `\n`s.

Comment: I don't think you can have a line break in a `plotmath` expression. Check out the `atop` function for two-line expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out how to do it manually which should work as long as I don't forget to make changes when the data change! :/