# How to customise axes labels in ggplot2 from a list of string inputs?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating a bunch of plots and have stored the appropriate labels for axes in my plots in a list:

`labels_list <- c("C[max,1] (mg/L)", 
                  "AUC[`6wks,1`] (mg*day/L)",
                  "somethingElse[subscriptText] (units*might/have*symbols)")`

My goal is to create labels where the text in the square brackets are subscripts. I have been using `parse()` which is okay, except:

- I can't figure out how to get the axes labels to be bold, though it is specified in my custom ggplot theme
- The asterisk disappears.

I know that `bquote()` is an option, but I haven't figured out how to use it if I just want to provide a list of strings as inputs like above. I'm definitely open to any suggestions and solutions provided.

**EDIT:** It seems that I cannot use my string inputs as-is? `labels_list` is extracted from a data frame and I would love to not have to, one-by-one, change this for plotting purposes. :-(

Comment: Would this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521699/how-to-add-subscripts-to-ggplot2-axis-text) help?

Comment: You really should study `help("plotmath")`.

Comment: Roland, I understand and have looked at plotmath, bquote, expression, parse, but that still doesn't help my original input. Do I have to manually have the inputs in these long, special formats for it to be correct?  I am asking this is because `labels_list` comes from a column in my dataframe that has the labels and units for the variables I am using. While parse() will automatically put the characters in the square brackets as appropriate subscripts, I still have the problems mentioned. If there's a better way to look at things, I will consider, but I don't really appreciate the redirection.

Comment: @IanCampbell Your post was helping a lot, I will vote to undelete it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Alright, feel free to edit it if you want.

Comment: @IanCampbell Done, see now. It's pratically your post with asterisks and tildes in this or that place. Most notably, in my opinion, to have 2 subscripts (`max,1` and `6wks,1`) the comma needs to be quoted.

Comment: If you want to use plotmath, you have to write plotmath syntax. Now, you could automate transforming your labels into correct syntax by using `gsub`. Personally I think plotting the asterix is just ugly. I would write `(mg~d~L^{-1})` or at least replace `*` with `%.%`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `expression` and `bold`:

```
labels_list <- c(expression(bold(C[max * ',' * 1]~(mg/L))), 
                  expression(bold(AUC["6wks"*','*1]~(mg * '*' * day/L))),
                  expression(bold(somethingElse[subscriptText]~(units * '*' * might/have * '*' *symbols))))

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1, y = 1), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x = labels_list[1], y = labels_list[2], caption = labels_list[3])
```

[image]

Comment: Tildes seem to be better than asterisks.

Comment: OP wants `(units*'*'*might/have*'*'*symbols)` (although better alternatives are provided by plotmath)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I sometimes get caught up in what I think is the "hard" part.

Comment: I've played with something like this, but I don't necessarily want to manually have to convert all of the strings in labels_list to accommodate this. It's also not entirely correct - I need the asterisk as a multiplier (the units are mg TIMES day PER litre) and everything INSIDE the brackets needs to be subscripted.

Comment: 1) `expression(bold(C[max * ',' * 1]~(mg/L)))` ; 2) `expression(bold(AUC["6wks"*','*1]~(mg * '*' * day/L)))` ; 3) `expression(bold(somethingElse[subscriptText]~(units * '*' * might/have * '*' * symbols)))`

Comment: Hi, to reiterate what I asked above with Roland: Does this mean I have to go and change `labels_list` to accommodate this? It's being pulled automatically from a column in the dataframe I am using, and I would prefer not to go in and manually do this if I can help it. Or if there's a more efficient way or different approach to thinking, I would appreciate learning.

Comment: @jnguyen The post linked to in my comment to the question changes the labels manually. The main tricks are to quote literals and to include spacing chars like `*` and `~` .

Comment: Yes, I can see that the labels were changed manually.... But I'm more interested in hearing if there is a more clever solution. I provided a small example but the reality is that I have 20+ variables to plot and want to do it in a controlled/programmatic manner...