# R Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : polygon edge not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

Whenever I use ggplot or any packages like pheatmap like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars)

#or 

pheatmap(sampleDistMatrix,
         clustering_distance_rows=sampleDists,
         clustering_distance_cols=sampleDists,
         col=colors)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found
```

I also get these warning messages:

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  no font could be found for family "Arial"
2: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  no font could be found for family "Arial"
3: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  no font could be found for family "Arial"
4: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  no font could be found for family "Arial"
5: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  no font could be found for family "Arial"
```

I tried following the advice on other posts like this one ([Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : Polygon edge not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581440/error-in-grid-calll-textbounds-as-graphicsannotxlabel-xx-xy-polygon)) and several other ones on google, but nothing worked. At that point I just uninstalled and reinstalled R studio, tried to delete all duplicate Arial fonts I somehow have in the Apple Fontbook even though it won't let me delete it completely and just shows that the duplicates are "off".
[image: Font book]

Technically I could try to force ggplot to use a different font, it doesn't solve the issue that I'm having with other R packages like pheatmap, so I really want to solve the underlying issue. I was able to plot a few days ago for R studio but now everything stopped working and shows the grid.Call error. Please help!

Some other stats that might help:

```
> ggplot2::theme_get()$text
List of 11
 $ family       : chr ""
 $ face         : chr "plain"
 $ colour       : chr "black"
 $ size         : num 11
 $ hjust        : num 0.5
 $ vjust        : num 0.5
 $ angle        : num 0
 $ lineheight   : num 0.9
 $ margin       : 'margin' num [1:4] 0points 0points 0points 0points
  ..- attr(*, "unit")= int 8
 $ debug        : logi FALSE
 $ inherit.blank: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_text" "element"


$serif
[1] "-*-times-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$sans
[1] "-*-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$mono
[1] "-*-courier-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$Times
[1] "-adobe-times-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$Helvetica
[1] "-adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$CyrTimes
[1] "-cronyx-times-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$CyrHelvetica
[1] "-cronyx-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$Arial
[1] "-monotype-arial-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$Mincho
[1] "-*-mincho-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"


> systemfonts::font_info()
# A tibble: 1 × 24
  path         index family style italic bold  monos…¹ weight width kerning color scala…² verti…³ n_gly…⁴ n_sizes n_cha…⁵ bbox  max_a…⁶ max_d…⁷ max_a…⁸
  <chr>        <int> <chr>  <chr> <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl>   <ord>  <ord> <lgl>   <lgl> <lgl>   <lgl>     <int>   <int>   <int> <lis>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 /System/Lib…     0 Helve… Regu… FALSE  FALSE FALSE   normal norm… FALSE   FALSE TRUE    FALSE      2252       0      10 <dbl>    9.23   -2.77      18
# … with 4 more variables: max_advance_height <dbl>, lineheight <dbl>, underline_pos <dbl>, underline_size <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names
#   ¹​monospace, ²​scalable, ³​vertical, ⁴​n_glyphs, ⁵​n_charmaps, ⁶​max_ascend, ⁷​max_descend, ⁸​max_advance_width
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: Are you using `showtext`? If so, have you loaded it and called `showtext_auto`? Just seeing the theme doesn't really help, but a reproducible example would (code + data that recreates the issue)

Comment: nope, did not use showtext at all! Plus I'm not sure if I can edit functions in a package I installed in R. I included some code I ran above--running either gives me the polygon edge error.